# https site with Django in text browser throws CSRF verification failed

Tags: python, django, emacs, https, lynx

I have a Django site that works well on a server using HTTPS protocol, I can use it with no problem with all kind of browsers.

The thing is that every time I try to use a text browser, I get a

Forbidden (403)

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a 'Referer header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent.
This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable 'Referer' headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS
connections, or for 'same-origin' requests.

Help

Reason given for failure:

    Referer checking failed - no Referer.
```

I have tried links, lynx, even w3m and eww on emacs, to no avail.

When I use a HTTP site (like when I'm using the manage.py runserver) I can use the site on text browsers with no problem, but my production server needs a HTTPS protocol and that's when I get  this error.

[ EDIT: just for testing purposes, I deployed an HTTP server for my django site on the production server. It works well on text browsers... ]

[ EDIT: given the message the server throws, why are Referer headers not been given? ]

Comment: CSRF token is stored in a cookie. Do you allow cookies in lynx?

Comment: yep, and it's obvious since http works then cookies work. Problem comes when using HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lynx is likely configured to not send the Referer header. Check /etc/lynx.cfg for "REFERER".

There are entries like `NO_REFERER_HEADER`. Make sure that's set to false. If that's not it, check around in that config for any other disabled referer headers.

Also related, the CSRF and Referer header debate: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16870

Comment: yep, it has to do with the browser configuration, lynx is working now. I'll have to look for the referer configs on other text browsers, in case they've got them...

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue that referer is been disabled and i have to re enable it but I am using Opera. can i know how can i solve the issue for opera browser @JavierNovoaC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER, SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE in your settings?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/security/#ssl-https

Comment: sorry, I added all those settings, but to no avail. Text browsers still don't allow me access with the same reason.... hmmmm